# Put image from depth sensor on top of original image from main camera

Tags: android, opencv, depth-buffer

We are creating an application where we want to measure the distance of each pixel from the camera. This works perfectly on iOS since the image returned by the OS is already recalculated to remove the shift caused by distance between depth and main camera. But on android, we get the original image for both cameras.
This means we have 2 images with different distortion and shift which we need to place on top of each other as you can see below:

[image]

Is there a way to calculate for each pixel on the right it's corresponding pixel from the image on the left?

---

**Edit:**
I found on the android developers page the following snippet:

> To transform a pixel coordinates between two cameras facing the same direction, first the source camera **CameraCharacteristics#LENS_DISTORTION** must be corrected for. Then the source camera **CameraCharacteristics#LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION** needs to be applied, followed by the **CameraCharacteristics#LENS_POSE_ROTATION** of the source camera, the translation of the source camera relative to the destination camera, the **CameraCharacteristics#LENS_POSE_ROTATION** of the destination camera, and finally the inverse of **CameraCharacteristics#LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION** of the destination camera. This obtains a radial-distortion-free coordinate in the destination camera pixel coordinates.

But I am not quite sure how to approach this with OpenCV. Any ideas?

Comment: in principle yes, if you have extrinsic calibration between both views. project the color image onto 3d geometry given by depth image. it becomes a "texture". I don't have the inclination to elaborate on that or figure out what APIs to use for that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Would you mind elaborating on that a bit? What I've managed so far is to convert Depth map into 3D points using `z * inv([[[K,0],[0,1]] x [[R,t],[0,1]]]) x [u,v,1,1/z]`. Now when I try to reconstruct the 3d points (using rotation matrix, translation vector and Intrinsic from the first camera and the following equation: `1/z * K x [R|t] x [x,y,z,1]`) I get wrong results. Any thought on this one?